# Exchange Web Service Managed API: How to get Task from E-Mail?

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I am using EWS to get some E-Mails, everything works fine but now i have to implement the "CompleteDate" which is set when someone uses this Red Flag in Outlook to set it to a Task.

I searched everything but i dont find a way to get the task from the E-Mail.. i tried to bind the Mail as a Task but id didnt work:

```
Task task = Task.Bind(service, item.Id);
```

Could anyone help me out here?

Answer (score 0):

What can help is make use of IlSpy for viewing the DLL.
A other great tool is EWSEditor. Its free and you can use it to read items based on EWS.
A e-mail cant be a task, you dont have the properties for the task.
To get the task you need to search by subject.

See example: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Exchange-2013-Find-tasks-0d2633ec
(With coding example)

Comment: unfortunately this doesnt work :(. Emails which are made into a "task" wont show up in the task search. also in EWSEditor there is nothing with a complete date at an email